# C++ 17 features in Visual Studio 2015 with Clang

Tags: visual-studio-2015, clang++

This is a perennial question here, but: does anyone know if there is a way to get Visual Studio 2015, with the Clang tool chain installed (tab for "cross compilation") to enable the 2017 features that Clang itself normally supports?

For example, I would like this to compile:

```
constexpr bool test(bool a){bool b= false; b = b || a; return b;}
static_assert(test(true),"");
```

With Clang itself, version 3.7, from command line with --std=++1z, this will compile correctly, but Visual Studio C++ is not yet at the level of supporting the full range of constexpr function features.  I had hoped that by cross compiling with Clang it would take them, but no luck.  I see that under properties, I'm only able to enable up through C++ 14 -- is this the core problem?  Namely that the visual studio parser itself at the IDE level can't yet understand the full constexpr functionality, even though the Clang compiler would actually compile it correctly?

Comment: OK, I've narrowed my issue.  The core problem is that while Clang itself would support --std=++1z, Visual Studio 2015 does not permit this level of the C++ language standard and overrides me if I force it, by just editing the language standard option on the properties page.  Does anyone know if there is a way to override the language standard level in the source code itself (e.g. via a compiler pragma, for example)?  I would then know that my code compiles even if VS claims the code has syntax errors: basically I would compile at level C++ 17, but be syntax-checked at level C++ 14.

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Command line > Additional Options setting, type -std=c++1z